# Overlap between Google Earth and Topographic OSM

Tags: openstreetmap, google-earth, topography

First, I have Google Earth and Garmin BaseCamp with [OSM](http://www.openstreetmap.org) maps. I would be satisfied if the solution is only available on one of these software. A third software that combine both view can be interesting if I can export to one of these.

Today I can draw a route on pedestrian road by using the routing of BaseCamp and I can as well export it to Google earth. But I did not find any option to merge both views.

Is it possible to have all pedestrian road with satellite view on any of these software and how?

Comment: I'm very interested in these topics but don't understand your question. Can you flesh things out a bit more, by editing it? I suggest deleting "satellite view" from title -- GE only has satellite view (and nothing else)

Comment: Google Earth have the roads as well, but it should be enabled on the left (down) menu: (Layer). But I do not find option to add other items like OSM data there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QGIS allows you to use Google Earth as background layer via the Openlayers plugin and Openstreetmap data as vector layer on top of it. Using OSM data via the Openlayers plugin would not bring the desired effect, as both are raster formats without opacity.

QGIS can also be used for routing using OSM data, if the data is preprocessed for that purpose.

QlandkarteGT  is able to overlay Maps in Garmin vector format (OSM or Garmin origin) over any available WMS or TMS services which should include Google imagery. Routing is possible online via the OpenRouteService (not only for cars), which uses OSM data as well.